# Connecting to db2 using cli fails with error code -1531

Tags: c++, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to connect to a remote db2 server using my code in c++. I am able to connect to the db2 server using the db2CLP to connect the server. I have configured the db2cli using the following commands:

```
db2cli writecfg add -dsn alias -database BLUDB -host hostname -port 50000
```

and even validated it using

```
db2cli validate -dsn alias -connect -user userid -passwd password
```

I am getting an error code of :  Native Error Code = -1531
when i use the function

```
SQLConnect(hdbc,
        (SQLWCHAR *)db1Alias,
        SQL_NTS,
        (SQLWCHAR *)user,
        SQL_NTS,
        (SQLWCHAR *)pswd,
        SQL_NTS);
```

And no error messages.
Can anyone point out if I am doing something wrong?

I have checked the error codes in IBM's page and did not find -1531 in its list. (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/db2z_n.html)

Here is the snippet of the code i am using :
I had picked this up from ibm's sample section(https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/cli/s-dbconn-c.html)

```
#define DBC_HANDLE_CHECK(hdbc, cliRC)              \
if (cliRC != SQL_SUCCESS)                          \
{                                                  \

    SQLWCHAR message[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1]; \
    SQLWCHAR sqlstate[SQL_SQLSTATE_SIZE + 1]; \
    SQLINTEGER sqlcode; \
    SQLSMALLINT length, i; \

    i = 1; \

    /* get multiple field settings of diagnostic record */
    while (SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, \
        hdbc, \ 
        i, \
        sqlstate, \
        &sqlcode, \
        message, \
        SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1, \
        &length) == SQL_SUCCESS) \
    { \
        printf("\n  SQLSTATE          = %s\n", sqlstate); \
        printf("  Native Error Code = %d\n", sqlcode); \
        printf("Error Meassgaes:%s\n", message); \
        i++; \
    } \

    printf("-------------------------\n"); \
  if (rc != 0) return rc;                          \
}
/* allocate a database connection handle */
    cliRC = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);
    ENV_HANDLE_CHECK(henv, cliRC);

    printf("\n  Connecting to the database %s ...\n", db1Alias);

    /* connect to the database */
    cliRC = SQLConnect(hdbc,
        (SQLWCHAR *)db1Alias,
        SQL_NTS,
        (SQLWCHAR *)user,
        SQL_NTS,
        (SQLWCHAR *)pswd,
        SQL_NTS);
    DBC_HANDLE_CHECK(hdbc, cliRC);
```

Actual result

```
  Native Error Code = -1531
Error Meassgaes:[
-------------------------
```

Expected :the connection should be established.

Comment: One link points to Db2 for z/OS, one to Db2 LUW. What product and version are you trying to connect to?

Comment: i am connecting to db2 LUW.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for [SQL01531N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic5.html#sql1531n). -1531 is transformed into the SQL+5 digits+N (negative), hence SQL01531N.

> The db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file contains database directory
>   information and client configuration parameters for use by some IBM
>   data server clients and drivers.
>
> The CLI/ODBC initialization file (db2cli.ini) contains various
>   keywords and values that can be used to configure the behavior of CLI
>   and the applications using CLI.
>
> This message is returned when a data source name is specified in a
>   connection string with the "DSN" connection keyword but the specified
>   data source name cannot be found in either of the following locations:
>
> - Specified with the "dsn alias" configuration keyword in the db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file
> - Specified as a section header in the db2cli.ini configuration file

How and where is **db1Alias** set in your code? What is the DSN alias name that is configured? Fix that and it should work.

Comment: This is the contents of db2dsdriver.cfg
`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<configuration>
  <databases>
    <database host="*******" name="SAMPLE" port="50000"/>
  </databases>

  <dsncollection>
    <dsn alias="testdb2" host="**********" name="Sample" port="50000"/>
    <dsn alias="testdb21" host="**********" name="SAMPLE" port="50000"/></dsncollection>

</configuration>
`
and db2cli.ini is empty

and dbalias is set to **"testdb21"**

Comment: I have added some rows in db2cli.ini `
[testdb21]
autocommit=0
`
I have also run `db2cli validate -dsn testdb21` and it returns `Success: The schema validation completed successfully without any errors.`

Comment: What alias name does your code use, when it is executing? Have you checked that value?

Comment: `db1Alias="testdb21";`

Comment: I have compiled and linked dbconn.c. While running it I get this output.
`THIS SAMPLE SHOWS HOW TO CONNECT TO AND DISCONNECT FROM A DATABASE.

-----------------------------------------------------------
USE THE CLI FUNCTIONS
  SQLAllocHandle
  SQLConnect
  SQLDisconnect
  SQLFreeHandle
TO CONNECT TO AND DISCONNECT FROM A DATABASE:

  Connecting to the database testdb21 ...

--CLI ERROR--------------
  cliRC = -1
  line  = 158
  file  = d:\db2odbctesttool\db2odbctesttool\db2odbctesttool\db2odbctesttool.cpp

  SQLSTATE          =
  Native Error Code = -1531
Error Meassgaes:[`

Comment: Test these commands, and **edit your question** to show both the command-line AND the results in plain text (don't add to comments).  Note the option `-connect` on each.   
`db2cli validate -dsn testdb21 -connect ` . 
`db2cli validate -dsn testdb21 -connect -odbcdsn ` . 
`db2cli validate -database sample:yourDb2-server-hostname:50000 -connect ` .
ALSO: edit your question to include the *VERSION DETAILS* of Windows, the Db2-server operating system, the Db2-client name and version, the Db2-server version+fixpack and whether any containerization or virtualization is in place.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was updating the Character set of the application. Previously it was set Unicode.

I went to solution properties->Genral->Character Set and set its value to `Not Set` and it started working.